# div inside php echo

Tags: php

i have this:

```
<?php  
       if ( ($cart->count_product) > 0) { 
           print $cart->count_product; 
       } else { 
           print ''; 
       }  
?>
```

and i need to put `print $cart->count_product` inside of `<div class="my_class"></div>`

I tried different ways, but i'm missing something in syntax. I'll be glad if someone could help.

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: <?php if ( ($cart->count_product) > 0) { print '<div class="my_class">'.$cart->count_product.'</div>'; } else { print ''; } ?>

Comment: @LifeIsShort Please see my answer. The `else` statement doesn't serve a purpose here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
echo '<div class="my_class">';
echo ($cart->count_product > 0) ? $cart->count_product : '';
echo '</div>';
```

If you want to have it inside your statement, do this:

```
if($cart->count_product > 0) 
{
    echo '<div class="my_class">'.$cart->count_product.'</div>';
}
```

You don't need the `else` statement, since you're only going to output the above when it's truthy anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
<?php  if ( ($cart->count_product) > 0) { ?>
         <div class="my_class"><?php print $cart->count_product; ?></div>
<?php } else { 
          print ''; 
}  ?>
```

Comment: Thanx, but i need class inside of if statement.

Comment: @LifeIsShort Edited the answer. See it.

Comment: Ugh, why keep exiting PHP and then re-entering? Also, the `else` statement serves no meaningful purpose here...

Comment: @BenM Oops. Didnt notice it. Now corrected it. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I think you misunderstood. My point is, why do you quite PHP execution to output simple HTML content? It's much cleaner to simply output it using `echo`, than having three opening PHP tags in as many lines...

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it around then.

```
<?php        
    if ( ($cart->count_product) > 0) 
    { 
        echo "<div class='my_class'>";
        print $cart->count_product; 
        echo "</div>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: There's no point to the `else` statement here at all.

Comment: @BenM You are correct about that. I just took it from the OP code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<div class"my_class">
<?php if ($cart->count_product > 0) {
          print $cart->count_product; 
      } else { 
          print ''; 
      } 
?>
</div>
```

Before hitting the `div`, we are not in PHP tags

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this,

```
<?php 
if ( ($cart->count_product) > 0) { 
  $print .= "<div class='my_class'>"
  $print .= $cart->count_product; 
  $print .= "</div>"
} else { 
   $print = ''; 
} 
echo  $print;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below sample, also you dont need the else clause to print nothing!

```
 <?php if ( ($cart->count_product) > 0) { ?>
           <div class="my_class">
               <?php print $cart->count_product; ?> 
           </div>
 <?php } ?>
```