# PHP - div inside echo function

Tags: php, html

I want to get the article-loop divs to populate inside the echo function in the while loop. I'm trying to create a dynamic pagination that prints the article-loop divs dynamically per page. This is pretty straightforward so for example, when the user changes the page, I want the next few divs to display on that page and so on.

```
<?php
class Pagination {
public $current_page;
public $per_page;
public $total_count;

public function __construct($page=1, $per_page=20, $total_count=0) {
    $this->current_page = (int)$page;
    $this->per_page = (int)$per_page;
    $this->total_count = (int)$total_count;
}

public function offset() {
    return ($this->current_page - 1) * $this->per_page;
}

public function total_pages() {
    return ceil($this->total_count/$this->per_page);
}

public function previous_page() {
    return $this->current_page - 1;
} 

public function next_page() {
    return $this->current_page + 1;
}

public function has_previous_page() {
    return $this->previous_page() >= 1 ? true : false;
}

public function has_next_page() {
    return $this->next_page() <= $this->total_pages() ? true : false;
}
}

$page = !empty($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$per_page = 2;
$total_count = 10;
$pagination = new Pagination($page, $per_page, $total_count);
?>

<html>
<body>
<div class="article-loop">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/CmU3tnl.jpg">
</div>
<div class="article-loop">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/TDdxS9H.png">
</div>
<div class="article-loop">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/39rpmwB.jpg">
</div>
<div class="article-loop">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/1lBZQ1B.png">
</div>
<div class="article-loop">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/Y5Ld4Qfh.jpg">
</div>
<div class="article-loop">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/8HumESY.jpg">
</div>
<div class="article-loop">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/CqCZBvk.png">
</div>
<div class="article-loop">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/wQVPRVp.png">
</div>
<div>
    <?php
        $i = $pagination->offset() + 1;
        $limit = $pagination->per_page;
        while($i<=$pagination->total_count && $limit>0) {
            echo '**IN HERE POPULATE THE ARTICLE-LOOP DIVS**';
            $i++;
            $limit--;
        }
    ?>
</div>
<ul>
    <?php
        if($pagination->has_previous_page()) {
            echo '<li style="display:inline"><a  href="index.php?page='.$pagination->previous_page().'">&laquo;</a></li>';
        } else {
            echo '<li style="display:inline" class="disabled"><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>';
        }
    ?>
    <?php
        for($i=1; $i<=$pagination->total_pages(); $i++) {
            echo '<a href="index.php?page='.$i.'"><li style="display:inline; margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px">'.$i.'</li></a>';
        }
    ?>
    <?php
        if($pagination->has_next_page()) {
            echo '<li style="display:inline"><a href="index.php?page='.$pagination->next_page().'">&raquo;</a></li>';
        } else {
            echo '<li style="display:inline" class="disabled"><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>';
        }
    ?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
<?php
    $i = $pagination->offset() + 1;
    $limit = $pagination->per_page;
    while($i<=$pagination->total_count && $limit>0) {
        echo '**IN HERE POPULATE THE ARTICLE-LOOP DIVS**';
        $i++;
        $limit--;
    }
?>
```

you can use something like

```
<?php
    $i = $pagination->offset() + 1;
    $limit = $pagination->per_page;
    while($i<=$pagination->total_count && $limit>0) {
?>
        **IN HERE POPULATE THE ARTICLE-LOOP DIVS**  // html content

<?php
        $i++;
        $limit--;
    }
?>
```

You should use second one. Many at times first one doesn't work properly.

Comment: I put the html content where you said and it doesn't work, it displays all the divs/imgs all at once. It is supposed to display three divs/imgs per page.

Comment: Make sure you are closing each and every if else statements at proper places

Comment: Can you please update your answer with the correct code because I can't seem to get it work.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501030/div-inside-php-echo once